# PDOException SQLSTATE[HY093]: yii-2 where and between Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii2

After long research I could not find a exact solution for the PDOException SQLSTATE[HY093]
I am using yii 2 frame work and i have problem when using between condition.

```
$query = SalesOrder::find()->where(['between','created_date', ':fromDate', ':toDate']); 
$query->addParams([':fromDate' => $salesReport->fromDate,':toDate' => $salesReport->toDate]);
$query->all();
```

tried differently same problem.

```
$qString1=':fromDate';
$qString2=':toDate';

$query = SalesOrder::find()->where(['between','created_date',$qString1,$qString2]); 
$query->addParams([':fromDate' => $salesReport->fromDate],[':toDate' => $salesReport->toDate]);
        $query->all();
```

Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: I think that you're missing some fields data.

Comment: hi, which fields data? I mean in the query or in DB @Yushox

Comment: What I learned from the above code is the place holder should not be sent as string i guess. i.e, with out single quote. I dont know i am confused...

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass parameter name in this case. try :

```
$query = SalesOrder::find()->where(['between','created_date', $salesReport->fromDate, $salesReport->toDate]);
$query->all();
```

Or, If you'd like to use parameter, try :

```
$query = SalesOrder::find()->where('created_date BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate'); 
$query->addParams([':fromDate' => $salesReport->fromDate],[':toDate' => $salesReport->toDate]);
$query->all();
```